# Trying to rigorously prove the law of total expectation

Tags: probability-theory, summation, expected-value, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

For simplicity, I'll consider only discrete sample space.

My work so far:

Let $Y$ and $W$ be random variables on a sample space $S$, which has a probability distribution $P$. So the probability of an event $s\in S$ is $P(s)$.

**Definition:** $E(Y|W)$ is a random variable defined on $S$ such that for all $s\in S$,
$$
E(Y|W)(s):=
\begin{cases}
\sum_{y\in\text{ran $Y$}} yP(Y=y|W=W(s)), &\text{if $P(W=W(s))\ne 0)$}\\
0, &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}.
$$

I am now trying to show that $E(Y) = E(E(Y|W))$. What I've done so far is the following.
$$
\begin{align}
\text{RHS} &=\sum_{\bar y\in\text{ran $E(Y|W)$}}\bar yP(E(Y|W)=\bar y)\\
&=\sum_{\bar y\in\text{ran $E(Y|W)$}} \bar y\sum_{s\in S}P(s) I_{E(Y|W) = \bar y} (s)\\
&=\sum_{s\in S: P(W=W(s))\ne 0} P(s)\sum_{y\in\text{ran $Y$}}yP(Y=y|W=W(s))\\
&= \sum_{y\in\text{ran $Y$}} y\sum_{s\in S:P(W=W(s))\ne 0} P(Y=y|W=W(s)) P(s)
\end{align}
$$

Now I have no idea how to further proceed. Any help?

Comment: sorry to be a bother, but $s \not\in S$, $s \subseteq S$

Comment: I agree with the notation comment of P.J.   Anyway, looking only at your last line,  it looks like you are done: just use the law of total probability to conclude that inner sum is the same as $P[Y=y]$.